# Rails f.select default selected

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have select

```
<%= f.select :visibility, collection_for_visibility_select, :include_blank => false %>
```

And a helper with values for select:

```
def collection_for_visibility_select
  [
    [l(:label_crm_contacts_visibility_project), Contact::VISIBILITY_PROJECT],
    [l(:label_crm_contacts_visibility_public), Contact::VISIBILITY_PUBLIC],
    [l(:label_crm_contacts_visibility_private), Contact::VISIBILITY_PRIVATE]
  ]
end
```

I want to add default select value to the select, and this is what I tried:

```
<%= f.select :visibility, collection_for_visibility_select, :selected => Contact::VISIBILITY_PUBLIC, :include_blank => false %>
```

it gave me default select value, but when i want to edit record and switch `visibility` to something else,i still got `VISIBILITY_PUBLIC`

How do I fix it?

Answer (score 2):

You can try this:

```
<%= f.select :visibility, collection_for_visibility_select, :selected => (f.object.visibility.nil? ? Contact::VISIBILITY_PUBLIC : f.object.visibility), :include_blank => false %>
```

It will read the value from the model first, and if it is nil, will use the default value.